# how to get the status of running tasks with TaskResult

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a running celery task. I want to get the status of the task with `django_celery_results`. But I noticed that the model only gets updated once the task completes running. How do I get the status of a running task with `TaskResult`?

Example views

```
def test(request):
    task_id = test_task.delay()
    status = TaskResult.objects.filter(task_id=task_id)
    print(status)
```

When I run the above view this is the result I get

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: please share your modals.py

Comment: Which model. TaskResult is generated. Please look [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding track_started parameter in @task decorator.

For instance:

```py
    from myproject.celery import celery_app

    @celery_app.task(
        bind=True,
        track_started=True
    )
    def my_task(self, parameter_a):
       pass
```